# how to import mysql database structure?

Tags: mysql-5, mysqldump

I have a database on Machine A. What I want is to dump my database in such a way that when I import it on another machine (Machine B) only the structure of the tables and Database are created.

**I want no data.**

Can `mysqldump` be used here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.

If you want to import the structure of the Database on some other machine there are some steps as follows

**1**.on Machine A(generate the dump without the data)

```
mysqldump -uuser -ppass --no-data --databases db1 db2 db3 > database_structure.sql
```

using `mysqldump` with `--no-data` will generate the dump without the data.

if you want only data dump do as(It will not contain the create statements)

```
mysqldump -uuser -ppass --no-create-info --databases db1 db2 db3 > database_data.sql
```

2.copy the  database_structure.sql on Machine B

Then you want to restore its structure on Machine B do

3.`mysql -uuser -ppass < database_structure.sql`

Then you have database structure available on the Machine B.

try it..